# How to keep the checkmark in a UITableView after the view disappears

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uitableview that's displaying multiple selections with a custom checkmark. When selected the rows value is save using NSUserDefaults. The problem is that despite the values being saved the checkmarks disappear from the table cell rows. I can't figure out why.

thanks for any help, I'm really stuck on this.

Here's the .h code:

```
    @interface CategoriesViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSString *selectedCategoryTableString;

    NSString *jsonStringCategory;

    int prev;

}

// arForTable array will hold the JSON results from the api

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arForTable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arForIPs;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *categorySelected;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *jsonStringCategory;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *accessoryView;

@end
```

and the .m code:

```
@implementation CategoriesViewController
@synthesize jsonStringCategory;
@synthesize arForTable = _arForTable;
@synthesize arForIPs = _arForIPs;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.arForIPs=[NSMutableArray array];

    self.categorySelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self reloadMain];

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
}

-(void) reloadMain {

    jsonString = @"http:///******";

    // Download the JSON
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jsonString]
                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding
                            error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *itemsTMP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create parser
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

    itemsTMP = [results objectForKey:@"results"];

    self.arForTable = [itemsTMP copy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arForTable count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
        cell.accessoryView.hidden = NO;

    }

    UIImageView *cellAccessoryImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png"]] ;
    UIImageView *cellAccessoryNoneImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]] ;

    if([self.arForIPs containsObject:indexPath]){
        cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryImageView;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryNoneImageView;
    }

    // Get item from tableData
    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[_arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // encoding fix
    NSString *utf8StringTitle = [item objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString *correctStringTitle = [NSString stringWithCString:[utf8StringTitle cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    cell.textLabel.text = [correctStringTitle capitalizedString];

    NSNumber *num = [item objectForKey:@"id"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [num stringValue];

    cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if([self.arForIPs containsObject:indexPath]){
        [self.arForIPs removeObject:indexPath];

        [self.categorySelected removeObject:[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];

    } else {
        [self.arForIPs addObject:indexPath];

        [self.categorySelected addObject:[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];

        NSLog(@"%@ categorySelected",self.categorySelected);

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSLog(@"%@ defaults categorySelected",[defaults arrayForKey:@"selectedCategoryTableString"]);

        NSString *string = [self.categorySelected componentsJoinedByString:@","];

        [defaults setObject:string forKey:@"selectedCategoryTableString"];

        NSLog(@"%@ STRING",string);

    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}



-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:NO];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;

}
```

Comment: Try adding a `[defaults synchronize];` after you set the values

Comment: @Alexander thanks. I'm sure I needed that, but it didn't solve the problem with the checkmarks disappearing. the data saves fine, it's just the checkmarks not displaying on the selected rows when you leave the view and come back

Comment: Don't use reuseidentifier and always create new cell object without using any identifier. No need to deque cell. Because in some cases there may be chance that you are getting some old cells having no checkmarks.

Comment: Also I am surprise that why you are talking about nsusedefaults. Since you are saving categoryarray in nsuserdefaults and in checkmarks you are using some another array

Comment: @BestCoder thanks for your help. How would I save the checkmarks in nsuserdefaults?

Comment: @BestCoder using reuse-identifier is very necessary if you have large number of cells you will not only get memory exceptions but also the scrolling will be lazy as it had to recreate cell every time a user scrolls. If you have custom cell the override **prepareForResue** method and clear or default things for each subsequent cell. Secondly if one is using UITableViewCell then have simple if check(s) to modify cell if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code has lots of memory leaks, please do use the static analyzer and/or instruments to fix them, few for them are pretty obvious like you initialized the SBJSON parser and did not release it, itemsTMP is another.

I have rewritten your code to be much more efficient and memory friendly:

```
@interface CategoriesViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *_items;
    NSMutableArray *_selectedItems;

    UIImageView *cellAccessoryImageView;
}

@end



@implementation CategoriesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _selectedItems = [NSMutableArray new];

    cellAccessoryImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png"]] ;

    [self reloadMain];

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
}

- (void)reloadMain
{    
    NSString *jsonString = @"http:///******";

    // Download the JSON
    jsonString = [NSString
                        stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jsonString]
                        encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding
                        error:nil];

    // Create parser
    SBJSON *parser = [SBJSON new];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

    if (_items) [_items release];
    _items = [[results objectForKey:@"results"] copy];

    [parser release];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];
        cell.accessoryView.hidden = NO;

    }

    NSDictionary *item = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([_selectedItems containsObject:item])
    {
        // preloaded image will help you have smoother scrolling 
        cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryImageView;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // Get item from tableData
    cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString stringWithCString:[[item objectForKey:@"name"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] capitalizedString];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[item objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue];
    cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;

    item = nil;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *item = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([_selectedItems containsObject:item])
    {
        [_selectedItems removeObject:item];
    }
    else
    {
        [_selectedItems addObject:item];
    }
    item = nil;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_selectedItems release];
    [cellAccessoryImageView release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Ok then you will be fine but unnecessary alloc/retain will cause the garbage collector to work much harder than it should be so you will not only lose precious CPU time but it will also drain the battery, thinking from an angle of performance and optimization.

Comment: thanks for the help with the code. would that display a checkmark if an item has been saved in nsuserdefaults?

Comment: can you tell me why do you need to save that in NSUserDefault?

Comment: do you want the checkmarks to be persistent when the app restarts or when you come back to that view again.

Comment: the checkmarks should remain checked when they come back to the view again. however, the table reloads with different data depending on another setting elsewhere. So, the table isn't static.

Comment: Then create a global array save the "id" not the entire object and compare if that "id" exists there or not. Did you understood or should i write up some code for you.

Comment: I understand the idea but will have trouble with the code syntax. if you could write up some code that would be very helpful thanks :)

Comment: You can download the code from [here](http://www.saplogix.net/StackOverflow/TableWithCheckMark.zip) it does the whole thing that you are trying to achieve and it will be for application life cycle but if you want it after restart as well then serialize the array to disk and deserialize when the app starts.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your table there is only one section. Try this approach and this will help you certainly.

In  `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  write following code;

```
    if([self.arForIPs containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]){
        cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryImageView;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryNoneImageView;
    }
```

And in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  write code as below,

```
       if([self.arForIPs containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]){
            [self.arForIPs removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        } else {
            [self.arForIPs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]
        }
```